# How do I write to a virtual file in Rust?

Tags: rust

Assuming I set up a logger with `fern` as below:

```rust
use log::{debug, error, info, trace, warn};

fn setup_logger() -> Result<(), log::SetLoggerError> {
    fern::Dispatch::new()
        .format(|out, message, record| {
            out.finish(format_args!(
                "{}[{}][{}] {}",
                chrono::Local::now().format("[%Y-%m-%d][%H:%M:%S]"),
                record.target(),
                record.level(),
                message
            ))
        })
        .level(log::LevelFilter::Debug)
        .chain(std::io::stdout())
        .chain(fern::log_file("output.log")?) // (a)
        .apply()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

However, I want to parametrize this `setup_logger` function with an optional path as `setup_logger(log_path: Option<std::path::PathBuf>)`.

So, I'd like to rewrite the line (a) above as:

```rust
// ...
.chain(match log_path {
    Some(path) => fern::log_file(path)?,
    None => // (b)
})
// ...
```

So, what do I do at the line (b) above? I have tried [std::io::sink](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.sink.html), but then match arms turn out incompatible since [fern::log_file](https://docs.rs/fern/latest/fern/fn.log_file.html) return a file.

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- Rust 1.62.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use intermediate values.

```rust
fn setup_logger(log_path: Option<&str>) -> Result<(), log::SetLoggerError> {
    let mut logger = fern::Dispatch::new()
        .format(|out, message, record| {
            out.finish(format_args!(
                "{}[{}][{}] {}",
                chrono::Local::now().format("[%Y-%m-%d][%H:%M:%S]"),
                record.target(),
                record.level(),
                message
            ))
        })
        .level(log::LevelFilter::Debug)
        .chain(std::io::stdout());

    if let Some(log_path) = log_path {
        logger = logger.chain(fern::log_file("output.log")?);
    }

    logger.apply()?;

    Ok(())
}
```